# ios swift parse: orderByAscending ist getting ignored

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When I run this query:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.includeKey("lesson")
query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in ........
```

The results are never sorted by data, in fact they are always sorted by objectId.

What is wrong in my query?

[image: this is my data sorted by date]
This is my data on parse, sorted by date

[image: this is my output based on the shown query]

This is my output on the device, sorted by objectId...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Try adding this to your above code in block, it worked for me:

```
let array:NSArray = self.queryobjectsArray.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
self.queryobjectsArray = NSMutableArray(array: array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This whole issue ended quite strange...
What I did before, like in other views within the same project, I fetched the data from parse and pinned it to the local storage and called a second method to fetch the data from the local storage. This way I have fast reachable data from local storage and update it in the background for later use.

For some reason, the  fetched data from online was sorted by date.
But the fetched data from the local pin was not and that was the reason, why my app displays the data in the wrong timeline.

I was not able to understand or solve this, but I helped myself by removing the local pinning and just grab the data from the internet.

I will show what the original process was:

```
var cardSetObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
    self.fetchAllObjects()
}

func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore(){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){

            var temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray
            self.cardSetObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else{
            println(error.userInfo)
        }
    }
}

func fetchAllObjects(){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    query.includeKey("lesson")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {

            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, withName:"CardSet", block: nil)
            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else{
            println(error.userInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

What I did at the end was to remove the `fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore` method and put the data into the NSMutableArray right in `fetchAllObjects`.

But I still wonder why I had this sorting issue with this code...
Maybe someone will know...